# Weird iPad2 location issue

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager

I am having weird issue with iPad2 location services.

I have two iPad2 devices right here on my desk. I just created a simple single view application and put the following code in the viewDidLoad of the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

}
```

On one iPad the usual permission dialog promts up and asks me to authorize location services and I can start tracking the user position.

On the other device (with the exact same code) nothing happens. The app is launched and just shows the white view of the controller but does not ask for permission at all. The only delegate method being triggered is the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus`

In both cases location services in the device settings are enabled.

Meaning either there is a hidden setting connected to the location services or the one iPad is broken?

Comment: This problem also occured on the iPad3. Probably a case for Apple Developer Support...

Answer (score 0):

Probably on other device this app was already installed and access was denied. To change location permissions you either have to reinstall app or go to settings->privacy->location services and allow app you want.